# Replacing string with special character

Tags: php

I am trying to pass id=%ADD_CODE as url params but when I am trying to get in php it is replacing %a with �. I need to keep the url param values the way it is.

Example

```
http://localhost/detect.php?id=%ADD_CODE%SUBID1&cid=%COOKIEID
```

Result when I am trying to echo key and value

```
id �DD_CODE%SUBID1
cid %COOKIEID
```

Any ideas?

Comment: www.localhost.com, really?

Comment: Do the needful, post your code.

Comment: %AD is going to mean "translate this byte to 0xad as soon as it comes in". If you _must_ use a % in a Query String, at a minimum you'll have to escape it in some way (does %% work?), but using urlencode() is the safest way.

Comment: @Phil Perry:I have tried using urlencode which fixes %AD issue but replaces %SUBID1 to %25SUBID1. reason I cannot change to %% because others systems are dependant on it.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: I had to change the company url with www.localhost for confidentiality reason

Comment: If you desire `$_GET['id']` to _literally_ contain `%ADD_CODE%SUBID1` as its value, either urlencode() it when producing the link, or replace % by %25 (same effect). `id=%25ADD_CODE%25SUBID1` _should_ show up in `$_GET['id]` as `%ADD_CODE%SUBID1`. Note that %SU isn't a valid hex code, so it was left alone, but it's safer to fix them all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode)

`localhost.com/detect.php?id=urlencode($userinput)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using urlencode() on your parameters:

https://www.php.net/urlencode